# Will I be penalized if i give someone who hasn't taken a test my test so he could study for his?

Tags: ethics, exams

I took this Mathematics class and this student asked me if I could ask the teacher to send my test so I could send to him so he can study for the test. It's not that I don't want to be a good person but thinking about doing it is eating me and  I feel if I do it so many things can go wrong for and ruin my future. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You’re under no obligation to provide your friend with a copy of the test, particularly if it makes you feel uncomfortable. Just politely decline, and if pressed further, say that you don’t think it’s appropriate to ask the instructor to share the materials that way.

As for the possibility of a penalty, I would not share “active” materials like quizzes or exams that other classmates still have to take, because that could be viewed as an academic code violation. Sharing something that everyone has completed and received grades on may or may not be penalized, based on an instructor’s or program’s explicit rules.

Comment: I agree - the actual test is not “normal” revision material available to all...

Comment: @SolarMike: That depends a lot on the respective rules. In my place, it is usually considered due diligence for students to revise with previous actual tests (which are never reused in a relevant way, though).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper then if that is "normal" the student can ask the teacher themselves directly - taking it through a third person is what is odd...

Comment: @SolarMike: Indeed; either, the teacher has nothing to do with the entire process (with the exams being passed down among students, starting with a student who took the respective exam themselves), or any student can ask the teacher directly.